# Why does Chang care so much Mei has left the company?

Tags: plot-explanation, hell-on-wheels

In Hell On Wheels, episode "Any Sum Within Reason" (season 5 episode 12) I'm confused with what happens between Mei Phong and Chang. Railroad workers get killed all the time. Why is Chang so adamant about hunting down this one? It's an absurd waste of resources. It's not as if one less worker would make or break their company. Right after Mei left the town, Bohanan went to Chang to try to buy out Mei's contract. This showed that Bohanan realized that Chang would go after her, how did he know that? And why did Chang start talking about prostitutes when Mei was a general laborer?

Comment: Are you asking multiple questions?  And try to come up with clear title

Comment: @AnkitSharma not it's one related question. How can the title be made better?

Comment: I have no idea about the show but by reading ti seems there are 2-3 unrelated question but I can be wrong. Anyway title should be specific to the question you have, currently it's too generic. You can refer other existing [plot explanation](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation) question to see how you can improve title.

Answer (score 1):

**Money.** (apparently this show taught you nothing ;)

Chang and his 'company' would go after her, because she's not a general laborer, she could be a whore earning *him*, as he says, anywhere from **$4~6 thousand dollars annually** (~$100k in 2017).

Chang is adamant, because as a slaver if you go soft, people start rioting. Economically, it would take months of searching for her for it to become absurd. Realistically, the bounty on her head would only increase with age due to the need of the 'company' to save face.

---

Chang found out about Mei because of the dress she gifted. Why would Mei's father be holding on to his wife's wedding dress... for his son.